# View results of a search in index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pg-search

What i'm trying to achieve is a product index page which shows:

(1) the result of my search if it matches a record in my database,

(2) all my products if the user input is blank (or if I simply visit the /products page), and

(3) a message which says the product hasn't been found if the product doesn't exist (is not in the database).

The code below returns me all the products if I insert a blank space in the search field or if I insert a string that doesn't match any record in the database, and a correct product if it's found it in the database.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <% if @products_search.present? %>
      <% @products_search.each do |product| %>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
          <%= product.name %><br>
          <%= product.description %><br>
          <%= humanized_money_with_symbol(product.price)%><br>
          <%= link_to "Show Product", product_path(product) %>
        </div>
      <% end %>

    <% elsif @products_search.blank? %>
      <% @products.each do |product| %>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
          <%= product.name %><br>
          <%= product.description %><br>
          <%= humanized_money_with_symbol(product.price)%><br>
          <%= link_to "Show Product", product_path(product) %>
        </div>
      <% end %>

    <% else %>
      <h1>No products found!</h1>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>


class ProductsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @products_search = Product.search_by_name_and_description(params[:term])
    @products = Product.all
  end
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :orders
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :user

  monetize :price_cents

  include PgSearch
  pg_search_scope :search_by_name_and_description,
                  against: [ :name, :description ],
                  associated_against: {
                      category: [ :name ]
                  },
                  using: {
                      tsearch: { prefix: true }
                  }
end

    <%= form_tag products_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'term', params[:term], placeholder: "What are you looking for?", :required => true %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Search!' %>
<% end %>
<br>
```

Comment: Please check the given answer below and feel free to accept answer if it helped you!

Comment: Unfortunately everything works except for the third query..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this code, i finally achieved what I was trying to do.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <% if params[:term].present? %>
      <% if @products_search.present? %>
        <% @products_search.each do |product| %>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
          <%= product.name %><br>
          <%= product.description %><br>
          <%= humanized_money_with_symbol(product.price)%><br>
          <%= link_to "Show Product", product_path(product) %>
        </div>
        <%end%>
      <% else %>
        <h1>No products found!</h1>
      <%end%>
    <% else %>
      <% @products.each do |product| %>
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
        <%= product.name %><br>
        <%= product.description %><br>
        <%= humanized_money_with_symbol(product.price)%><br>
        <%= link_to "Show Product", product_path(product) %>
      </div>
      <%end%>
      <%end%>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

(1) the result of my search if it matches a record in my database,

(2) all my products if the user input is blank (or if I simply visit the /products page), and

(3) a message which says the product hasn't been found if the product doesn't exist (is not in the database).

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <% if @products_search.blank? %>
      <%unless @products.blank?%>
        <% @products.each do |product| %>
          <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
            <%= product.name %><br>
            <%= product.description %><br>
            <%= humanized_money_with_symbol(product.price)%><br>
            <%= link_to "Show Product", product_path(product) %>
          </div>
        <%end%>
      <%else%>
        <h1>No products found!</h1>
      <%end%>     

    <% elsif @products_search.present? %>
      <% @products_search.each do |product| %>
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
        <%= product.name %><br>
        <%= product.description %><br>
        <%= humanized_money_with_symbol(product.price)%><br>
        <%= link_to "Show Product", product_path(product) %>
      </div>
      <%end%>
    <% else %>
      <h1>No products found!</h1>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: (1) the result of my search if it matches a record in my database OK

(2) all my products if the user input is blank (or if I simply visit the /products page) OK

(3) a message which says the product hasn't been found if the product doesn't exist (is not in the database) doesn't works.

Comment: @LuisCarlosQuarta Hi, are you not getting `No products found!` error ? in 3rd case?

Comment: yes in the 3 case, when i search for something i know is not in the database it simply gets me all the products and there is no errors. I copied pasted your code exactly how it is. I updated my post with my search view at the end.

Comment: @LuisCarlosQuarta Hi I understand your requirement but in 3rd condition you won't be able to know if product exists in database or not in that case @product_search will return blank array same as in (2) all my products if the `user input is blank (or if I simply visit the /products page)` so i'm not sure if pg_search will return anything in case of 3rd that will meant to guess that product not exists in database, hope you understand it well.

Comment: You can make the third condition work by checking the presence of `params[:term]`. If `params[:term].present?` returns `true`, but `@product_search` is empty, then display the message for No Products Found. If `params[:term].present?` returns false, then show all products.